# Question about Contacting previous employer post-hire question

Tags: discussion

[Contacting previous employer post-hire](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/102607/contacting-previous-employer-post-hire)

Hello, trying to understand what about this question is "too simple" to ask.

I wanted to know if calling previous employers of an already hired employee for references is allowed in the state of California (state included in case of legalities).

To me, its pretty clear what I am asking. I don't want to delve into any more details as its not really what I want to ask about. I just want to know about calling previous employers of an already hired employee for references.

Is the quesiton out of place here? Is this more legal than workplace?

How can I improve this or why is this wrong?

Comment: Does it matter that your simple, one-line question was closed? You already got a definitive answer: "Yes you can". That seems as clear as your question. You really can't expect much more of  an answer than that, given the simplicity of the question.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere did I complain about it being "closed"? did I ask it to be reopened? do you have a problem with me asking for a reason/explanation? thought meta is a place I can try to ask questions to understand how its operated

Comment: @Zero if you want you can consider posting your question again, with more details as explained (no point in trying to salvage the other one now with -8).

Comment: @DarkCygnus thanks i appreciate that. but I really only wanted to know about if there are any blatant issues (legal or otherwise) with the act of contacting a previous employer for references post-hire, in general. there is nothing about a specific situation that I am really wondering about at this point. I'm now leaning more towards: maybe I was just wondering about the legal side of it, but I just didn't know at the time and am now figuring that out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is the quesiton out of place here? Is this more legal than workplace?

Absolutely not, it is in fact a Workplace related question. It could be more legal if you rephrase it in such way, but right now the single line it contains is about a workplace situation and is on-topic.

> How can I improve this or why is this wrong?

First, the comment you obtained indicating it is "too simple" I think referred to the fact that it was a plain question: no details, almost no context. *Not* to the fact that it is not worthy of a question.

You post was closed because it did not contain enough information to give you a sound and thoughtful answer. As the Notice indicated *"Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need"*.

I suggest you try **including more details to your question**. **Why** do you want to ask such reference, what is the **situation between your company and that other**, what problems are forcing you to take another approach, or to hesitate about it, rather than just asking for the reference.

These are just some examples I can think of, but you can surely think of more so you have enough information to make an effective post with all relevant information needed to answer it. Consider editing it, and pinging me here when you do, so we can see if other support the idea of reopening.

Comment: Yes, the lack of a "why" was the reason I voted to close. This is something that is most definitely legal, so it would have been helpful to know why the OP thought it might not be acceptable. Is it a legal question? A professionalism question? A company policy question? Each of these would garner very different responses.